# UIImagePickerController() Swift 3

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, swift3

I am writing a program using swift3 to get photo from library but when I always get this debug message

```
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
```

And this is my code to open photo library and pick the image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func importFromLibrary(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Even it doesn't give me any error but I really want to fix this debug message.